# Why are the allowed epochs set by the coremltools builder ignored?

Tags: swift, keras, coreml

I have created a NN in *keras* and converted it trainable with *coremltools*.

```py
spec = keras_converter.convert(
    model,
    input_names=["input"],
    output_names=["output"],
    respect_trainable=True
).save("EasyMultilayerPerceptron.mlmodel")
```

To train multiple epochs on the iPhone, I used the coremltools builder.

```py
spec = coremltools.utils.load_spec("EasyMultilayerPerceptron.mlmodel")
builder = coremltools.models.neural_network.NeuralNetworkBuilder(spec=spec)
builder.set_epochs(epochs=50, allowed_set=[5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000])
coremltools.utils.save_spec(builder.spec, "XORMultiLayerPerceptron.mlmodel")
print(builder.spec.neuralNetwork.updateParams.epochs)
```

The print command logs following:

```
defaultValue: 50
set {
  values: 1
  values: 5
  values: 10
  values: 50
  values: 100
  values: 500
  values: 1000
  values: 5000
}
```

Integrated in my Xcode Project, the model shows, that the default epochs are 50.
However when training the model, it always just trains one single epoch. When setting the `MLModelConfiguration` to 50 epochs, I get the error message, that only 1 epoch is allowed. Why is that, and how can I fix that?

```swift
modelConfig.parameters = [MLParameterKey.epochs: 50]
let updateTask = try MLUpdateTask(
    forModelAt: self.modelURL,
    trainingData: trainingBatch,
    configuration: modelConfig,
    progressHandlers: MLUpdateProgressHandlers(
        forEvents: [.trainingBegin,.epochEnd],
        progressHandler: { (contextProgress) in
            print(contextProgress.event)
        }) { (finalContext) in
            do {
                print("Finished Training in \(time) s")
                try finalContext.model.write(to: self.modelURL)
            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
        })
```

Comment: Inside the progress handler, what does `print(context. model.modelDescription.parameterDescriptionsByKey[.epochs])` say?

Comment: When I change epochs to 1 again, to bei able to run it, this shows, default, min and max epochs are set to 1. While my `.mlmodel` file is still showing default epochs: 50

Comment: Btw. I'm using `Xcode 11.2.1`, `coremltools 3.1`, `MacOS 10.15.1` and `iOS 13.1.3`

Comment: Is self.modelURL a URL inside your app bundle or inside your app's documents directory? If the latter, make sure you're copying the mlmodelc from your app bundle into the documents directory first. My guess is that maybe you first made a model with epochs=1, then changed it to allow more epochs, but the app is still using the old mlmodelc.

Comment: You are right, my model wrapper class only stored the new compiled model into the documents dir. if no other model with the same name exists. 
Thank you for your help